# Trouble with Stacked bar graph without pooling

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science, bioinformatics

I have a clear idea of what I would like to plot, but I am not sure where to start using matplotlib/seaborn.

I have ~999 **unequal** lines of 0s, 1s, and 2. Here is an example of one line:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

I would like to make a horizontal plot where each number maps to a color of some set unit length.

This looks like a stacked bar plot. But I believe the the functionality of plt.bar would pool values such that there could only be three contiguous colors. However I need to implement the graph such that there could be any number of switches between colors.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 1000 rows I guess you're better off if you display your data as an image using [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) rather than a bar chart. Put your data (`0`, `1` or `2`) in an array of 999 rows and as many columns as the longest sequence, initilize that array with `-1`.

Example with just 100 rows for better readability:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# generate some sample data
n, m = 10, 20
a = np.random.randint(0, 3, (n,m))
s = np.random.randint(int(m/2), m, n)
for i in range(n):
    a[i,s[i]:] = -1

# show them as image
cmap = plt.matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['w', 'r', 'lime', 'b'])
plt.imshow(a, cmap=cmap)
```

[image]

You can then adjust axis ticks and labels as needed.

Comment: I didn’t expect a psychedelic trip on Stack Overflow but here we are.